# Get users that have payment due in one day sql

Tags: mysql, sql

This is probably easy to do but I can't seem to get my head around it. I have a user table that has a next_payment DATETIME column which gets update every month. I would like a query to get all the users where their next_payment DATETIME is in one day from the current datetime.

I tried something like this but it also gets me users where their next_payment is due in like 15 minutes. Not good

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE next_payment >= NOW() AND next_payment <= NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

I also tried something like this but this doesn't work either as it gives me all users that had next_payment datetime like 2 or 3 months ago (Not good).

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE next_payment <= NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: you can use `between` though

Comment: What would be the query with BETWEEN @maSTAShuFu

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Need to `Cast` the datetime field to date so you can include all data within the period and use `between`

`SELECT * FROM 
users 
WHERE 
cast(next_payment as date)
     between cast(NOW() as date) 
     AND cast(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY as date)`

Comment: If I do so, let's say I run the query today March 7th at 11:50 pm and I have a user who has next_payment due on March 8th at 1:50 AM (in 2 hours), it will return me that user.

Comment: what's your requirement? is it based on date or time?

Comment: cast the field to date will read as a date without the time. if the user is between DATES then should be in the result

Comment: I need to take the time into account. For example, one day from March 7th 19:35:54 is March 8th 19:35:54

Comment: so what's wrong with your OP when the result return a 15 minute old request?

Comment: you need to be clear with your OP.... should be between period but only  over number of hours... which you failed to supply

Comment: Because I don't want users to complain later and say that I expected them to pay 15 minutes after receiving a notification

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

`SELECT * FROM users 
  WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,NOW(),next_payment) <= 24`

Comment: I would prefer to get the future DATETIME, not the ones from the past

Comment: I understand what you want, you want those w/ 24 hours before the next_payment date. You could make use of the `TIMESTAMPDIFF()`

where `TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,NOW(),next_payment)` would check how many hours until next_payment, ideally you'd want to return users who are `<= 24` hours

Answer (score 0):

DATEDIFF works fine in MySQL:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    users 
WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(next_payment, NOW()) = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d585f/1/0) for this example.